# compare 2 values within 2 ranges

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have 2 columns with both positive and negative values. Let the columns be A and B. I need to find a condition that matches both values of A and B.

i.e. if -3.485 < a < +2.1254 value and -4.002 value < b < +2.0058 value then only give output if not leave it blank.

The condition should satisfy both a1 and b1, similarly for all the cells and give the output.

The data is the following

```
No B  G
3   -1.715772722    -3.054865035
5   3.588890805 -3.475612176
6   6.752195683 -6.766356639
7   4.614783751 -7.026582153
8   2.365077193 -2.988718743
9   -1.789974105    -4.252785509
10  2.054340923 -10.79873773
11  0.642314339 -1.953243473
12  0.619638393 -10.5032906
14  -2.372712122    -4.078433599
15  -0.336235015    -7.9877767
16  -3.938464913    -0.878690891
17  -5.580748439    -6.884853407
18  5.936213662 -2.359464975
19  5.31799345  -2.585210068
21  -0.496620035    -4.729243662
23  2.067383731 -5.987820517
24  1.69158942  -6.053157846
25  6.861025116 -1.905004097
26  3.659342479 -2.268393163
28  2.276700373 -2.708745304
30  -4.659115278    -10.70395635
```

I have tried the following

```
=IF(AND(−3.94661308<I2<4.10089412,−3.2482405<K2<2.2681055),A2,"")
```

and this

```
 =IF((AND(I2>=−3.94661308, I2<=4.10089412, −3.2482405>=K2, K2<=2.2681055 )), y2, "")
```

It returns it as #NAME?

I'm not sure where I am going wrong

Comment: Could you share the sample data (Screen Shot)  from worksheet & also the formula you have tried  so far ?

Comment: I have edited the question and shared the sample data and the formulas I have tried.

Comment: Are −3.94661308,  4.10089412, −3.2482405 & others the base values to check in both Columns ?

Comment: Yes. It has to check these 4 values in these columns i.e.  I2 between −3.94661308 and  4.10089412; and K2 in between −3.2482405 and 2.2681055

Answer (score 0):

Formula in D2 (dragged down):

```
=IF(AND(B2>=$B$25,B2<=$B$26,C2>=$C$25,C2<=$C$26),"Matched","Not matched")
```

Worksheet:

```
   A              B               C            D
 1 3        -1,715772722    -3,054865035    Matched
 2 5        3,588890805     -3,475612176    Not matched
 3 6        6,752195683     -6,766356639    Not matched
 4 7        4,614783751     -7,026582153    Not matched
.......................................................
 9 11       0,642314339     -1,953243473    Matched
.......................................................
22 28       2,276700373     -2,708745304    Not matched
23 30       -4,659115278    -10,70395635    Not matched
24 
25 From     -3,485          -4,002
26 To       2,1254          2,0058
27
```

Of course, addresses in a formula may be replaced with exact values.